# Converting loop to Java 8 streams

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can I convert the following looping code to simple Java 8 streams?

```
List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>(); 
...   
int column = 0;

for(String text:headers){
    Cell cell = header.createCell(column++);
    cell.setCellValue(text);
}
```

Comment: By lambdas do you mean streams? This wouldn't be a particularly good fit for a stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams won't be needed. Use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and [`Iterable#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
AtomicInteger column = new AtomicInteger(0);
headers.forEach(text -> header.createCell(column.getAndIncrement()).setCellValue(text));
```

Whether that's more readable is up to you.

Comment: whether this preserves the order from the list?

Comment: @jaks Yes, it has identical ordering to a regular for-each loop. As described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).