# How can I convert this for loop to java 8 stream analog

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I convert this code to java 8 stream.

Tried to use for each, but failed. For loop code is working.

```
for(RestrictedInstrument restrictedInstrument : restrictedInstruments){
    List<Identifier> identifierList = restrictedInstrument.getIdentifier();
    setTicker(matrix, identifierList);
}
```

`setTicker()` method should be called with matrix Object and `identifierList`.

Comment: Is restrictedInstruments a List ?

Comment: `restrictedInstruments.forEach(x -> setTicker(matrix, x.getIdentifier()));` if `restrictedInstruments` is a `List`. `Arrays.stream(restrictedInstruments).forEach(x -> setTicker(matrix, x.getIdentifier()));` if it's an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting loop to Java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604649/converting-loop-to-java-8-streams)

Comment: Why do you want to convert the code to a Java 8 stream? What forEach code did you write that failed? What was the error? What is the type of `RestrictedInstrument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`List.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
restrictedInstruments.forEach(i -> setTicker(matrix, i.getIdentifier()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming restrictedInstruments is list, first you map to identifierList, then you use Stream.forEach() to execute setTicker(...) method

```
restrictedInstruments
  .stream()
  .map( RestrictedInstrument::getIdentifier )
  .forEach( identifierList -> setTicker(matrix, identifierList) )
```

For arrays just use Arrays.stream( restrictedInstruments )

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the list and then simply pass consumer which just calls setTicker function.

```
 restrictedInstruments.stream()
.forEach(identifierList -> setTicker(matrix, identifierList.getIdentifier()));
```